# I keep getting this error: An internal error occurred during: "Converting 'AngularTest' to angular project..."

Tags: java, json, eclipse, angularjs

I am trying to test out Karma on my eclipse project but I got hung up with this error when first trying to convert it to AngularJS:

**An internal error occurred during: "Converting 'AngularTest' to angular project...".
loader constraint violation: when resolving method "tern.resources.TernProject.set(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/eclipsesource/json/JsonValue;)Lcom/eclipsesource/json/JsonObject;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, tern/eclipse/ide/internal/core/resources/IDETernProject, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for resolved class, tern/resources/TernProject, have different Class objects for the type java/lang/String;Lcom/eclipsesource/json/JsonValue;)Lcom/eclipsesource/json/JsonObject; used in the signature**

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be great, for anyone trying to help you, if you would supply some more detail on what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Question is about AngularJS Eclipse. Perhaps you have several version of minimal-json plugins?

Comment: Thanks for the response....I only have json_simple-1.1.jar...where could I go to see if I have more than one plug-in?

Comment: Last version of AngularJS Eclipse 0.7.0 is based on minimal-json_0.9.1 (not  json_simple-1.1).  json_simple-1.1 was used for an very old version of AngularJS Eclipse (which was 1.0.0). If you had installed it, I suggest you to use a fresh eclipse installation.